# ¿Cómo inserto un post usando la API de Blogger?

Tags: google-api, oauth2, blogger, google-oauth

Me han mandado a hacer un proyecto que integre OAuth 2.0 y la API de Blogger (todo con JavaScript). Hasta ahora, he podido implementar todos los métodos CRUD y el OAuth, pero cuando tengo que insertar, la API me retorna un error 403 "The caller does not have permission". No he podido encontrar la solución, ¿qué podría hacer?

INSERCIÓN (siguiendo la documentación de la [API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using?hl=es-419)):

```js
const apiURLPost = `https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/${blogId}/posts`;

const repsonse = await fetch(apiURLPost, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "blog": {
            "id": `${blogId}`
        },
        "title": "A new post",
        "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
    })
})
```

OAUTH (usando solo GIS):
https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis?hl=es-419

```
  var client;
  var access_token;

  function initClient() {
    client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: 'clientId',
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger',
      callback: (tokenResponse) => {
        access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
        localStorage.setItem("token", access_token)
      },
    });
  }
  function getToken() {
    client.requestAccessToken();
  }
  function revokeToken() {
    google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(access_token, () => {console.log('access token revoked')});
    localStorage.removeItem("token")
  }
  function displayToken() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("token"))
  }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Sin ver tu codigo, va a ser dificil ayudarte...

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué tipo de permiso le estás dando a tu autorización? Para poder crear entradas necesitas un scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger`. Muestra tu código que crea la autorización pulsando en [edit]. O revisa el mismo token generado, en el cual te debería decir el alcance que tiene. Por lo que comentas, parece que sólo le das un scope para leer, pero no para modificar contenido.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo primero que revisé fue eso, el **scope**, puse el de la API de Blogger pero aun así, no está funcionando. Es extraño porque me deja eliminar y editar.

Comment: Pues podría ser un problema de cuotas o algo así. Creo que hay un límite para crear entradas. No sé exactamente cuál es ese límite y en la Consola de Google puedes revisar tus cuotas, para ver si no has sobrepasado el límite. Otra cosa que podrías intentar es poner el ID a mano, asegurándote de usar uno que no exista, sólo por depurar que no haya un problema con esa variable. Me refiero a `${blogId}`